# Syntax error unexpected '<' on line 11

Tags: php

> Syntax error unexpected '<'

Code is:

```
$new_notifs = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Notifications WHERE ToID='$MyID' AND IsNew='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $new_notifs = mysql_num_rows($new_notifs);
    if($new_notifs>0) {
        $new_notif_block = " disBlock";
    } else {
        $new_notif_block = NULL;
        $new_notifs = NULL;
    }
        <div id='header'>
        <div id='headerContainer'>
            <h1 id='pageLogo'>
                <a href='./' title="Home"></a>
            </h1>
            <div id='fbRequestsJewel' class='fbJewel<?php echo $new_friend_active; ?>'>
                <span class='fbJewelNotif<?php echo $new_friend_block; ?>' id='requestJewelNotif'><?php echo $new_friends;?></span>
                <div id='fbJewelRequestsPopup' class="jewelPopup">
                    <div class='fbJRPcover disBlock'></div>
                    <div class='fbJewelTitle'>
                        Friend Requests
                        <a class='fright lightBlue noBold' href='find.php'>Find Friends</a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: why there is  '> ' id='requestJewelNotif'> at the end..??

Comment: And the more important question, why didnt you format your code properly before you ask for help?

Comment: please add code highlighting

Comment: You're pasting HTML in the middle of PHP. `?>` before HTML.

Comment: close php tags before putting your html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

Close your PHP tag:

```
    $new_notifs = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Notifications WHERE ToID='$MyID' AND IsNew='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $new_notifs = mysql_num_rows($new_notifs);
    if($new_notifs>0) {
        $new_notif_block = " disBlock";
    } else {
        $new_notif_block = NULL;
        $new_notifs = NULL;
    }
    ?>
    <div id='header'>
```

Note the `?>` before `<div id='header'>`.

At the moment, you're not closing your PHP tags, which means that PHP is trying (and failing) to parse `<div id='header'>`, hence the `Syntax error unexpected '<'` error.